# QML TapHandler onLongPress get position coordinates

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to show the context menu in a position where a user touched a screen with long-press. I found the TapHandler signal **longPress** that looks like its going to solve my problem, but it doesn't have any input parameters like **eventPoint**:

```
TapHandler {
  onLongPressed: {
    if (Qt.platform.os == "android" || Qt.platform.os == "ios") {
      // contextMenu.x = eventPoint.position.x 
      // contextMenu.y = eventPoint.position.y
      contextMenu.open()
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: you can use [point.position](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html#point-prop) to get the point currently handled. But imho it looks like a bug :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best way to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, regarding point: HandlerPoint: "The event point currently being handled. When no point is currently being handled, this object is reset to default values (all coordinates are 0)."
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html#point-prop